# Dynamically and programmatically create the layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, view

I am trying to create a layout programmatically where there is one `ImageView` with two buttons. Now the `ImageView` will be in the center, and the buttons will be at the bottom of the layout.  But I am not able to do it.  Here is my code

```
public class StackView extends RelativeLayout {

    ....................

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM|Gravity.LEFT);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM|Gravity.RIGHT);


    addView(imageview, 0, params);
    Button button=new Button(context);
    button.setText("left");
    button.setGravity(Gravity.START);
    addView(button, 1, params1);
    Button button1=new Button(context);
    button1.setText("right");
    button.setGravity(Gravity.END);
    addView(button1, 2,params2);
}
```

Comment: and why dont you want to inflate it from xml?

Comment: It's just a basic research for me,no other issue.@pskink

Comment: Have you tried changing LayoutParams ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer.Here how I do it.

```
            Button button=new Button(context);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            params1.addRule(BELOW,card.getId());
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
           // params2.addRule(BELOW,card.getId());
            params2.addRule(ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,button.getId());

            addView(imageview, 0, params);

            button.setText("left");
            button.setGravity(Gravity.START);
            addView(button, 1, params1);
            Button button1=new Button(context);
            button1.setText("right");
            //button.setGravity(Gravity.END);
            addView(button1, 2,params2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`activity_main.xml`

```xml
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.demo.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/layout" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private RelativeLayout layout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

        //for imageview
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramBtn = new 
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);        
         paramBtn.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        imgView.setId(1);
        imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        imgView.setLayoutParams(paramBtn);
        layout.addView(imgView);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        param1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

        Button btn1 = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        btn1.setId(2);
        btn1.setText("Submit");
        btn1.setLayoutParams(param1);
        layout.addView(btn1);


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param2 = new    
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        param2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,btn1.getId());
        param2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        Button btn2 = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        btn2.setId(3);
        btn2.setText("Submit-2");
        btn2.setLayoutParams(param2);
        layout.addView(btn2);

      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but according to my research I don't want to use any xml file.Anyway I have got my solution.